# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory: could not resolve host: sheets.googleapis.com

Tags: r, shiny, googlesheets4

I am having a problem with googlesheets4 on my shiny app. Every time I update the sheet with new data, it causes an error with the app on our server. Here is the error log.

error log showing the error with host sheets.googleapis.com:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.